# How to crop image without knowing the height of image using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have 100s of screenshots taken from website of varying height. I would like to crop header of the images by 50px from the top irrespective of the height of the image.

```
convert -crop autoxauto+0x50 image-input.png image-output.png
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract and retain the top 50 rows, or that you want to remove the top 50 rows and keep the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Mark's answer, however I found a simpler solution:

```
convert image-input.png -chop 0x50 image-output.png
```

Answer (score 2):

If you start with this image where the two bars are both 50 pixels tall:

[image]

You probably mean:

```
convert start.png -crop x50+0+0 top.png
```

[image]

Or:

```
convert start.png -crop x50+0+50 bottom.png
```

[image]